# Unexpected output in multithreaded program

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class ThreadSafe implements Runnable {
  int arr[]=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
  int sum=0;
  public void run() {
    int result=sum();
    System.out.println("for "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"the value        is"+result);
  }

  public int sum() {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
      sum=sum+arr[i];
      System.out.println("calculating sum for      thread"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"sum ="+sum);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
      } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public static void main(String...d) {
    ThreadSafe ts=new ThreadSafe();
    ThreadSafe ts1=new ThreadSafe();
    Thread t=new Thread(ts);
    Thread t1=new Thread(ts1);
    t1.start();
    t.start();
  }
}
```

I was expecting the output not to come 15. because the sum method is not synchronized so more then one thread can execute the sum method at the same time

What I was expecting that because the 2 thread's will execute the sum method instantly so the output should not be 15 because the first thread will update the value of sum to some value which will be read by the another thread.

So my question is why the output of the program come out the way I'm expecting even though i haven't synchronized the sum() method?

Comment: add volatile to sum. It indicats that it is concurrently changed.

Comment: `arr` is not static, each ThreadSafe is getting its own copy.  Neither is `sum`.

Comment: *What's wrong with the code?* -> For starters, the formatting (or the lack of it)... ;)

Comment: @Wug: Your point is well made (see my answer), but he's modifying the `sum` variable, not the source array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating two instances of `ThreadSafe`, each with their own `sum` instance variable.

If you want them to overwrite each other (I'm assuming this is just playing around), create two `Thread`s on the same instance of `ThreadSafe`. Also, mark your `sum` variable as volatile to indicate that it can be changed by another thread (to avoid internal caching of the value if the compiler detects that it is not changed elsewhere within the method).

For example, change your `main` method to this:

```
public static void main(String...d) {
    ThreadSafe ts=new ThreadSafe();
    Thread t=new Thread(ts);
    Thread t1=new Thread(ts);
    t1.start();
    t.start();
  }
```

And the beginning of your `ThreadSafe` class definition to this:

```
class ThreadSafe implements Runnable {
  int arr[]=new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
  volatile int sum=0;
```

Comment: that means if i will declare sum as a local variable in the method then the result will come as i'm expecting

Comment: @krishnaChandra: No, the opposite. To keep your code as it is now (with two instances of `ThreadSafe`, you'd need to make the `sum` variable `static`. But why not just create two `Thread` objects off of the same `ThreadSafe` instance?

Comment: @krishnaChandra No, but you can make it `static` for instance.

Comment: @adam :sir Can you please provide the code you are explaining in your answer.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: ya after doing what you suggest i got 30 by each of the thread.but still confusing with the code i declared the sum  method  as synchronized  got 15 for the first thread ......ok ...but why 30 is the output by the second thread it should be the 15 again

Comment: @krishnaChandra: You can't know (at all) the order in which the steps will get executed. To get 30, you may have had both threads complete the addition steps before either of them wrote to the console. Running it again may give you a different result.

Comment: @AdamRobinson: it ok .....but why there is need to declare sum as a volatile .....is there any specific region behind that.

Comment: @krishnaChandra: I've given a (very) brief reason behind why you need to declare it as volatile in my answer. You may want to read up on multi-threading and what these terms mean, specifically as they relate to Java.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15857/discussion-between-krishna-chandra-and-adam-robinson)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two instances of `ThreadSafe` being handled by different threads. For producing your desired result it should be like one instance and multiple threads working on that same instance

Comment: Or the two instances sharing a single variable.

Comment: @brimborium: It seems more idiomatic (to me) to have two threads operating on the same instance, though obviously either would work in this case.

Comment: @AdamRobinson I agree, though sharing a single variable might be easier to understand for a beginner...